# Transform gpg_keys received via GitHub Api into armored

Tags: javascript, pgp

How can i get public keys back into their `armored` look ? like --- BEGIN PU...

I'm working with `kbpgp` that does not support any other key types, armored only, therefore i'd convert them back and import into kbpgp manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub api for gpg_keys does not provide entire public key, it share the packet chunk of the `keyid` entry. It does not provide another packet bytes like userid, therefore not so much custom gpg implementation can work with it as with general key. Anyways, it useful only for verifiyng `keyId`s.
[More](https://medium.com/@linuxenko/playing-with-github-user-api-gpg-keys-f685bcefc61c#.lz72rpnef)..

Comment: Nice find! i din't knew that